# Prove or dismiss that SUM of series divided by its partial sum squared converges.

Tags: calculus

We are given that $a_n >0$ for every natural $n$ and that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges. and for every $n>=1$ exists a $\Delta_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$.

Prove or dismiss: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n/\Delta^2_n)$ converges.

I have no clue how to start with this one, would appreciate any kind of help! :]

Comment: Hint: for $n > 1$, $\frac{a_n}{\Delta_n^2} < \frac{a_n}{\Delta_n\Delta_{n-1}} = \cdots$.

Comment: =$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/\Delta_{n-1})$ $-$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/\Delta_{n})$..and then both converge by Delambert theorem?

Comment: You don't need that, it is a telescoping series.